# An Alternative puzzle

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> Gold
>   Triple
>   I've eaten 2 from a bakers dozen

I'm a man. Am I straight or am I gay?

Hint:

> The title is a hint

Hint2:

> I look out my windows and see I CANNOT use my Raincoat

Comment: This is a real puzzle, just incase anyone thinks its a joke.

Comment: is the puzzle to tell you whether you are gay or not or is there something else lol

Comment: Haha the answer is either straight or gay there isn't anything else

Comment: My brain is melting with these one! XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

partial answer:

> *Gold*, could be either atomic number i.e: 79 or symbol i.e: Au 
>  *Triple* could be either 3,three or triple gold i.e: AuAuAu or 237 
>  *I've eaten 2 from a bakers dozen*. A bakers dozen is 13, could be 11. 
>  maybe the answer is written in some sort of leet, but this is only a guess

edit: definitive answer:

> I♥♂, you ar gay then ;) 
>  as chronocidal said, you may have done a mistake, is gold = tantalum?=73=I  triple=3=♥ 11=♂  with alt+number

Comment: Press [Alt] on your keyboard, then type a number and let go?  I'd have expected Tantalum rather than Gold though!

Comment: @Chronocidal with alt+num I got Oφ♂

Comment: and with tantalum, Iφ♂

Comment: 237 is φ, 3 is ♥

Comment: Why would you say gold=tantalum?

Comment: @IdkWhy mmmmh, yeah, don't know, works with talantum as Chronocidal said

Comment: Wasn't completely what I was looking for but i'm accepting as its close enough. I was going for Gold=1st=1 alt1=☺ so it would be ☺♥♂. Tantalum works better tho tbh lol. Well done!

Comment: @Jon.G Aha - so, we can also deduce that you're un-tanned, as you didn't go with Silver? ☻  (I said "I'd have expected Tantalum" as "O" didn't make much sense, and "I" did)